# place video on html page and make it responsive using bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am using bootstrap `mPurpose-master` theme. in this there is a part where there is a feature to place 3 blocks in a row and it is completely responsive.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                DATA ONE
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                DATA TWO
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6>
                DATA THREE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish to modify this part and would like to place a video in the middle of the screen/row and also make it responsive. For this i tried the following code. I left the first and the third div empty and placed the video in second div.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <video controls autoplay height="340" width="267" >
                    <source src="<? echo $video_link;?>" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working fine, but the issue is that it stops becoming responsive if i change the height and width of the video.

Second method that i tried is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <video  controls autoplay >
                <source src="<? echo $video_link;?>" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it is placing the video to the left and also is not making it responsive

At present the height and width of the video is too small. I would like 3 things. 
1) Increase the size of video to 640*360. 
2) Place it into center of the screen. 
3) Make it responsive.

Comment: in third div `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">` instead of `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6>`

Comment: @Tanya Sinha it isn't working

Comment: i have just pointed out the error in your code....if you create a fiddle then it will be easier for us to find the solution for you

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that you want to have in this row is the video, then you shouldn't have to use columns. If you apply the following CSS, you should get the video to be centered and responsive:

```
#video-containing-div video {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now, hard-coding the width and height into your HTML will cancel the video's "responsiveness". Also, I may have missed something here, but if you try to increase the size of the video with styling, you are only going to blow it up and lose in picture quality. To increase the video's size you need to shoot it in higher resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a div which centers the video on your page? In that way you don't even have to use that bootstrap column. Try something like this in your HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="video">
        Paste your video in here
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your CSS should look something like this:

```
.video {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 640px; //since you want the maximum width of the video to be 640px
}
```